# Update list object to database using InsertAllOnSubmit

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to save changes to database using Linq 2 Sql, using InserAllOnSubmit method, it neither inserts the records nor throws errors/exceptions.
Please help me if I have done any mistake in the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void UpdateCoachingAssessmentInfo(CoachingAssessmentViewModel model)
    {
        Guid userGuid = model.UserGuid;
        try
        {
            using (var ctxAdmin = new MemberDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.CONFIG_KEY_MEMBER_CONNECTION_STRING].ToString()))
            {
                List<CAT> userCat = new List<CAT>();
                List<QandR> userQr = model.QuestionResponseIds;
                foreach (var x in userQr)
                {
                    CAT objCAT = new CAT();
                    objCAT.userGuid = model.UserGuid;
                    objCAT.Question_Id = x.QuestionId;
                    if (x.OptionId != null && x.OptionId != 0)
                    {
                        objCAT.Option_Id = x.OptionId;
                        objCAT.Option_Response = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objCAT.Option_Response = x.OptionResponse ?? null;
                        objCAT.Option_Id = null;
                    }

                    objCAT.createDate = DateTime.Now;
                    objCAT.updateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    userCat.Add(objCAT);
                }
                ctxAdmin.CATs.InsertAllOnSubmit(userCat);
            }
            UpdateCoachingAssessmentEligibility(userGuid);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to save changes to db.", ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `ctxAdmin.CATs.SubmitChanges()` after `ctxAdmin.CATs.InsertAllOnSubmit(userCat)`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1.insertallonsubmit?view=netframework-4.8)

> The added entities will not be in query results until after SubmitChanges has been called.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: After adding 
ctxAdmin.CATs.InsertAllOnSubmit(userCat);
ctxAdmin.SubmitChanges();

It throws a exception: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

Comment: It means you are inserting a row with duplicating Primary Key. Check the Primary Key field of the entity you are trying to insert (`userGuid `, `Question_Id ` or `Option_Id `).

Comment: CATs entity doesn't have any constraints at all.

Comment: I'm marking Nam Le suggestion as answer, for the comment he made on Primary Key constraint, my issue was something related to that.
Thanks Nam Le.